# What is the temperature dependency of p/T in the ideal gas?

Tags: gas-laws

This is about the ideal gas equation $$pV=nRT$$ to plot ${p}\over{T}$ against $T$, where ${nR}\over{V}$ is constant. How would this graph look like?

Comment: So... what is the temperature dependence of (p/T), where (p/T) = (nR/V)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what 'temperature dependence' means, and it's not used at this level.

Comment: In other words, if you double T, what will be value of (p/T)?

Answer (score 2):

A straight line parallel to temperature axis.

It will be of the form $y = c$,  where $c$ is a constant, mathematically.

Also if you take any value of $\frac{p}{T}$ it will always give same value, because $\frac{nR}{V}$ is a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, rearrange the equation to get $\frac{p}{T}$ in the left hand side:
$$\frac{p}{T} = \frac{nR}{V}$$

As the question says, $\frac{nR}{V}$ is always a constant. So, $\frac{p}{T}$ is also a constant. In other words, I double the temperature, I double the pressure as well, still giving me $\frac{p}{T}$, to make sure $\frac{nR}{V}$ is always constant.

So if one were to draw graph, because is always one value, even if we change the value of $T$, this has to mean that a graph of $\left(\frac{p}{T}\right)$ against $(T)$, will give a straight line graph with gradient $0$, and intersecting the $y$ axis at magnitude $\left(\frac{nR}{V}\right)$, since $\frac{p}{T}$ remains constant.

Answer (score 2):

See the following:

$$PV = nRT \implies \frac PT = \frac{nR}{V} = \text{const.}$$

So whatever you do with $T$, $P/T$ won't change, so it would be a constant horizontal line.